# Проблемы с dropdawn в Materialize 1.0.0-rc.2

Tags: input, focus, materialize-css

Всем привет, когда открыт любой дропдаун и я нажимаю на инпут, то дропдаун закрывается и фокус с инпута пропадает. Может кто-то сталкивался с этим(

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
          <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
      </div>
      <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

      <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('select').formSelect();
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
```

Вот тут можно посмотреть:https://codepen.io/Maximuz/pen/eLpYMK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил! Закомментировал следующие строки в библиотеке:

```
if (this.options.autoFocus) {
  this.el.focus();
}
```

Comment: 1. Не надо менять код в библиотеках. 2. Не надо портить библиотеки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я согласен, но иначе я не смог обойти эту проблему(